# Add a window padding to guake

Tags: linux, command-line, unix

Text is too near the edge of the screen, I'd like to allow a small *10 pixel* padding on all sides to comfort my eyes. Is this possible? I'm using `guake`.

Answer (score 2):

`guake` is a python script so you can simply edit it.

1. Open the `guake` script in your favorite text editor (`gedit`, or `vim` or whatever you use):

   ```
   sudo emacs /usr/bin/guake
   ```
2. Find this line:

   ```
   width = 100
   ```

   It should be in the `get_final_window_rect(self)` function, on my `guake` it is line 821.
3. Change that to :

   ```
   width = 99
   ```

   then save the file.
4. Close and restart `guake`:

   ```
   guake -q && guake &
   ```

---

The best I could come up with for adding a padding was to add a border around the `guake` window, not exactly what you need but it might be a decent workaround. Edit the file `/usr/share/guake/guake.glade`, go to the `<widget class="GtkNotebook" id="notebook-teminals">` section and change this line (line 24 in my version):

```
<property name="show_border">False</property>
```

to

```
<property name="show_border">True</property>
```

This has the effect of adding a border around the glade window which acts kinda like adding padding. not perfect, but it might do for a workaround.

Another (uglier) option is to change

```
 <property name="decorated">False</property>
```

to

```
<property name="decorated">True</property>
```

on line 11, in `<widget class="GtkWindow" id="window-root">`. That will make `guake` look like a normal window so again, there will be space between the edge of the screen and `glade`. Of course, if you are willing to do that, you may as well use a normal terminal emulator and avoid this entire issue.

Comment: As much as admire this quick hack, the overlay isn't applied to the whole window. I edited line `821`.

Comment: What overlay? On my system that simply makes the window smaller in all directions resulting in a space between he edge of the window and the endges of the screen. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: No, I just wanted a padding not a margin.

Comment: @WearetheWorld updated my answer with a couple of (ugly) workarounds.

Comment: I would have raise an upvote army on this. Stupid world!

Comment: Oh no, I won't.

Comment: @SepehrLajevardi umm... OK?

Comment: @terdon OK!​​​​